# Is Basestation a must for PR2?

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going to test a PR2 quick soon and I already check the information in [PR2 beta training workshop](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Events/PR2BetaTraining).

When I was checking the tutorials in PR2 support, I saw the [unpacking PR2 video](http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/Tutorials/OutoftheBox). The video implies that I can directly connect to PR2's wireless network with laptops right after unpacking the PR2, and after sshing, I can run programs on PR2.

The confusing thing is about the next tutorial, [Configuring the PR2 Basestation](http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/Tutorials/ConfiguringBasestation).I don't understand why  I need to set up basestation.

Is this a must for using PR2? And if so, what's the main function of Basestation?(I don;t understand [this explanation](http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/Tutorials/ConfiguringBasestation#Why_Use_a_Basestation.3F).)

Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47902/is-basestation-a-must-for-pr2?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In day-to-day use the main purpose of the basestation is to ensure that regardless of whether or not the PR2 is plugged into the building network, or connected via wifi, you can always access it using the same IP/hostname. You can certainly use a PR2 without the basestation, but the access point in the PR2 is only 802.11g, so you'll get much lower bandwidth than with the basestation.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-11-13**:
What is building network?  Thank you~